WhatsApp Business Cloudapi return same Wamid
I've developed a PHP app, created a Facebook app, configured the webhook and everything is working fine, I can send and receive WhatsApp messages.
My problem is with the Webhook status, all time return the same Wamid then don't can update the message status in my database because never return the correct wamid.
How can solve this problem?
Thanks
[statuses] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => wamid.HBgMNTczMTIzNzE1MzExFQIAERgSOTNFMjVGOEIwNzBEOTYyNTIyAA==
                             [status] => read
                             [timestamp] => 1730568659
                             [recipient_id] => 57312371xxxx
                         )
              )

)

Other

[statuses] => Array
              (
                  [0] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => wamid.HBgMNTczMTIzNzE1MzExFQIAERgSOTNFMjVGOEIwNzBEOTYyNTIyAA==
                             [status] => delivered
                             [timestamp] => 1730568237
                             [recipient_id] => 573123xxxxxx
                             [conversation] => Array
                                               (
                                                   [id] => 0cc1831f2d1a88833130efb81986b0ea
                                                   [origin] => Array
                                                               (
                                                                   [type] => referral_conversion
                                                               )
                                               )
                             [pricing] => Array
                                          (
                                              [billable] =>
                                              [pricing_model] => CBP
                                              [category] => referral_conversion
                                          )
                        )
          )


when u send a message u will get a id in return in api rsponse
and when that message is delivered, ready by contact , or failed by any reason ,
then You will get that wamid, with statuses update , in status key .
